# Proving density of $\mathbb{Q}^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

I'm looking for a relatively simple way to prove that $\Bbb {Q}^n$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}^n$ given $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$

Thanks

Comment: Every ball with centre $x$ contains a "cube" with centre $x$.

Comment: To get a rational point $(r_1,\dots,r_n)$ within $\epsilon$ of $(x_1,dots,x_n)$ it is enough to make $|x_i-r_i|\lt \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}$ for all $i$.

Comment: Start with $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and nonempty, and let $x = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n) \in U$. By openness there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that
$$B(x; \varepsilon) = \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n : \lVert x-y \rVert < \varepsilon \} \subseteq U$$
For each $1 \le i \le n$ pick $q_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x_i \le q_i < x_i + \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{n}}$; such a $q_i$ exists by density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. You need to show that $q = (q_1, q_2, \cdots, q_n) \in U \cap \mathbb{Q}^n$, so that $U \cap \mathbb{Q}^n \ne \varnothing$.